# Cubic reciprocity proof

Tags: number-theory

I'm working on the proof of cubic reciprocity. I don't understand the proof of the following theorem.

> Suppose that $N(\pi)=p$ congruent of 1 modulo 3. Among THE associate of $\pi$ exactly one is primary.

Does anyone know a proof for this theorem with steps which i hopefully can understand?

My gratitude is great,

Answer (score 2):

Let $\pi$ be an element in the ring of integers $D$ of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_3)$ with $N(\pi)=p\equiv 1 \bmod 3$, where $\zeta_3$ denotes a primitive third root of unity. Since $D=\mathbb{Z}\oplus \zeta_3\mathbb{Z}$, we may write $\pi=a+b\zeta_3$. We have six units in the ring $D$, namely $\pm 1,\pm \zeta_3,\pm \zeta_3^2$. Hence the associates of $\pi$ are given by $\pm \pi,\pm \zeta_3\pi,\pm\zeta_3^2\pi$. Since $p=N(\pi)=a^2-ab+b^2$ and $3\nmid p$ by assumption, not both $a$ and $b$ are divisible by $3$. Now we have to consider all six associates, use the assumptions above to see that exactly one of these is indeed primary (this takes a few case considerations about $a$ and $b$ modulo $3$, which you will easily find. ).